# Why is my wifi router delaying broadcast UDP packets?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, python, udp

I have a Python program running on my raspberry pi that opens a socket to receive broadcast packets (actually ArtNet lighting protocol). The pi uses its built-in wifi to connect to a D-link wireless router, which my Mac also connects to. The router is not connected to the internet or any other devices. It is dedicated to this application.

**Pi <-> D-link router <-> Mac**

Everything is physically within a couple meters so the signal strength is fine.

Raspberry Pi code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.1.255", 6454))
```

The problem is that the packets (lighting commands) sometimes get delayed noticeably. I'd say 7 times out of 10 there seems to be no delay but other times the delay is from approximately a half second up to 5-10 seconds.

It seems like the router is possibly dropping packets or delaying them somehow.

I tried using a home internet router and the delay was much less frequent and less severe. Not sure the brand of that router, it was in a different house.

I tried switching to a wired network through an ethernet switch and the problem disappears completely.

Then I tried switching to unicast via wifi and the problem disappears as well! Works flawlessly over wifi. But I have multiple devices and I can't use unicast in my final application.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.1.101", 6454))
```

I looked through the settings in the router and couldn't find anything that seemed to be related to handling broadcast packets. What might be the mechanism causing the delay or dropped packets, and is there a way to fix it?

Note: posted on stackexchange but someone suggested I post here since it's more likely a configuration issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387104/why-is-my-wifi-router-delaying-broadcast-udp-packets

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced exactly the problem you describe, in the same field (smart home control). It seems that certain WiFi routers have this behavior, while others do not. This causes UDP broadcast to be unusable for control purposes. We've checked and the problem is independent of the source machine, happens also from macOS and ESP32.

Your options are:

1. Change the WiFi "router" to another model.
2. Reconfigure the router to remove the broadcast delay (if anyone learns how to do this for specific router models, do tell!)
3. Use unicast instead.

For using Unicast, this can work if you either (a) know your destination IP addresses in advance, or (2) receive replies to the broadcast packets or receive other broadcasts from the peers. In the latter case, you can keep track of the peer IPs as you discover them and then have a loop where you send the broadcast plus unicasts to each peer. This assumes that there's some built-in deduplication in your protocol (ArtNet) to avoid double action.